# Javascript delay within object method

Tags: javascript, class, javascript-objects

I'm making a program where an class object has a number of methods - for instance this one:

```
    heal() {
        console.log(`The ${this.type} heals itself!`);
        consoleSpan.innerHTML = `The ${this.type} heals itself!`;
        consoleSpan.innerHTML += `<br><br>The ${this.type} gets +3 health`

        this.health += 3;
        refresh();
        changeTurn();
    }
```

This works fine. But I'm wanting to make a slight delay so that I can add in some animations before the values and text update, but when I try that it no longer works. If I do this:

```
    heal() {
        setTimeout(function(){

            console.log(`The ${this.type} heals itself!`);
            consoleSpan.innerHTML = `The ${this.type} heals itself!`;
            consoleSpan.innerHTML += `<br><br>The ${this.type} gets +3 health`

            this.health += 3;
            refresh();
            changeTurn();

        }, 500); 
    }
```

Then the this.type isn't working, and for instance it's console logging "The *undefined* heals itself!"

I assume the fact that it's adding a function within a function is somehow stopping *this.* from working, but I can't work out how to get around that.

If useful, here's the full code for that class object:

```
class character {
    constructor(type, health, damage, defence, poweredUp, shieldUp) {
        this.type = type;
        this.health = health;
        this.damage = damage;
        this.defence = defence;
        poweredUp = false;
        shieldUp = false;
    }
    
    attack() {
        console.log(`The ${this.type} attacks!`);
        consoleSpan.innerHTML = `The ${this.type} attacks!`;

        if ((this.damage - this.opponent.defence) <= 0) {
            this.opponent.health --;
            consoleSpan.innerHTML += `<br><br>The ${this.type} does 1 damage.`;
        } else {
            this.opponent.health -= (this.damage - this.opponent.defence);
            consoleSpan.innerHTML += `<br><br>The ${this.type} does ${(this.damage - this.opponent.defence)} damage.`;

        }
        if (this.poweredUp == true) {
            this.damage -= 3;
            this.poweredUp = false;
        }

        if (this.opponent.shieldUp == true) {
            this.opponent.shieldUp = false;
            this.opponent.defence -= 3;
        }

        refresh();
        changeTurn();

        if (this.opponent.health <= 0) {
            death();
        }
    }
    
    heal() {
            console.log(`The ${this.type} heals itself!`);
            consoleSpan.innerHTML = `The ${this.type} heals itself!`;
            consoleSpan.innerHTML += `<br><br>The ${this.type} gets +3 health`

            this.health += 3;
            refresh();
            changeTurn();
    }

    powerUp() {
        if (this.poweredUp == true) {
            console.log("Already powered up!")
        } else {
            console.log(`The ${this.type} is powering up!`);
            consoleSpan.innerHTML = `The ${this.type} is powering up!`;
            consoleSpan.innerHTML += `<br><br>The ${this.type} gets +3 damage` 
            this.damage += 3;
            this.poweredUp = true;
        }
        refresh()
        changeTurn();
    }

    raiseShield() {
        if (this.shieldUp == true) {
            console.log("Shield's already up!");
        } else {
            console.log(`The ${this.type} puts up its shield!`);  
            consoleSpan.innerHTML = `The ${this.type} puts up its shield!`;
            consoleSpan.innerHTML += `<br><br>The ${this.type} gets +3 defence`
            this.defence += 3;
            this.shieldUp = true;
        }
        refresh();
        changeTurn();
    }
}
```

Comment: _"I assume the fact that it's adding a function within a function is somehow stopping this"_ - value of `this` inside a regular function depends on _how_ the function is called. If you want the value of `this` inside the callback function of `setTimeout` to be same as inside the outer method, use an arrow function instead: `setTimeout(() => { ... }`

Comment: perfect, thank you very much!